# Is this representation of "Einstein's riddle" correct?

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

I am trying to formalize ["Einstein's riddle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rDVz_Fb6HQ) in predicate logic to practice.

A thief has stolen a rare fish and is hiding in his house. The street has five contiguous houses. Each house has exactly one of each of the following properties:

- The Nationality of the owner (N)
- The beverage that the owner drinks (B)
- The colour of the House's walls (H)
- The brand of cigarette smoked (S)
- The animal dwelling there (A)

  *Note that $A_5$, the fish, isn't listed in the clues for obvious reasons.*

Is this a reasonable/correct formalization of the problem? If not, why not? Whether or not it's correct, how can it be improved?

**Rule 1**: Each house/house owner has exactly one of each type of property (e.g. Only one nationality). There are five of each properties and each one is assigned to a house.
$$
\forall P \in \lbrace N,B,H,S,A \rbrace \space \forall i \in  \lbrace 1,2,3,4,5 \rbrace \space \exists x (P_i(x) \land \forall y \Rightarrow y=x)
$$
**Rule 2**: Iff a house $x$ is directly to the left of house $y$, then house $x$ cannot be the 5th house and house $y$ must be one more than $x$
$$
\forall x \forall y \space T(x, y) \iff x \in \lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace \space \land y = x+1
$$

**Clue 1**: The Brit lives in the house with the red walls.
$$
\exists x \space N_1(x) \land H_1(x)
$$

**Clue 2**: The Swede has a dog.
$$
\exists x \space N_2(x) \land A_1(x)
$$

**Clue 3**: The Dane drinks tea.
$$
\exists x \space N_3(x) \land B_1(x)
$$

**Clue 4**: The green house is directly to the left of the white house.
$$
\exists x \exists y \space H_2(x) \land H_3(y) \land T(x,y)
$$

**Clue 5**: The owner of the green house drinks coffee
$$
\exists x \space H_2(x) \land B_2(x)
$$

**Clue 6**: The bird owner smokes Pall Mall
$$
\exists x \space S_1(x) \land A_2(x)
$$

**Clue 7**: The owner of the yellow house smokes Dunhill
$$
\exists x \space S_2(x) \land H_5(x)
$$

**Clue 8**: The man living in the centre (3rd) house drinks milk.
$$
B_4(3)
$$

**Clue 9**: The Norwegian lives in the 1st house.
$$
N_4(1)
$$

**Clue 10**: The cat owner lives next to the man who smokes Blends.
$$
\exists x \exists y \space A_3(x) \land S_3(y) \land \lnot (T(x,y) \iff T(y,x))
$$

**Clue 11**: The horse owner lives next to the man who smokes Dunhill.
$$
\exists x \exists y \space A_4(x) \land S_2(y) \land \lnot (T(x,y) \iff T(y,x))
$$

**Clue 12**: The man who smokes Blue master drinks root beer.
$$
\exists x \space S_4(x) \land B_5(x)
$$

**Clue 13**: The German smokes Prince.
$$
\exists x \space N_5(x) \land S_5(x)
$$

**Clue 14**: The Norwegian lives next to the blue house.
$$
\exists x \exists y \space N_4(x) \land H_4(y) \land \lnot (T(x,y) \iff T(y,x))
$$

**Clue 15**: The man who smokes Blends lives next to the man who drinks water.
$$
\exists x \exists y \space S_3(x) \land B_3(y) \land \lnot (T(x,y) \iff T(y,x))
$$

Comment: "_Note that $A_5$, the fish, isn't listed in the clues for obvious reasons._" What is wrong with "The fish is next to the house where the Russian lives", or "The person with the fish smokes Camel"?

Comment: @Arthur Nothing. But the additional instructional material called out the fact that there wasn't a clue about the fish yet you can still work it out. The lack a fish-clue makes it seems harder.